# How to direct TeXShop to all all .aux files, also in subfolders, such that they can be trashed?

Tags: texshop, auxiliary-files

I am writing a report in TeXShop with a main file (main.tex) and several chapter files, which I include with the `\include` command. 
The main.tex looks as follows:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\include{chapters/one}
\include{chapters/two}
\end{document}
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
root
|
|-main.tex
|
|-chapters
    |
    |-one.tex
    |-two.tex
```

When compiling, .aux files are created in the root folder but also in the chapters folder.
When something goes wrong and I want to trash the .aux files I press the "Trash Aux Files" button in the console or hit "Trash Aux & Typeset" in the menu.

However, this only trashes the .aux files in the root folder, not in the chapters folder.
Is there a way to direct TeXShop to the aux files in the subfolders?
I am using TeXShop 3.26 with pdflatexmk 4.37

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After an e-mail to the developer of TexShop it turned out that I didn't read the manual.
Going to `Help -> TeXShop Help Panel... -> How do I configure TeXShop -> Hidden Preference Items` I found:

> Sometimes a more extensive cleanup is desirable. If the option key is
>   held down while choosing "Trash AUX Files," TeXShop uses the "% !TEX
>   root = ..." and "Set Project Root" mechanisms to find the root file.
>   It then moves all files in the folder of this file and any subfolders
>   of this folder to the trash if they have appropriate extensions,
>   regardless of the names of the files. This behavior can be made the
>   default behavior for "Trash AUX Files" without using the option key;
>   issue the command
>
> defaults write TeXShop AggressiveTrashAUX YES

This solved my problem.