# Why TeXShop doesn't erase the "lol" file? Is it laughing at me?

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texshop, mactex, auxiliary-files

**TeXShop** (with the standard **MacTex distribution**, and using the **pdflatexmk** engine) creates a lot of pesky temporary auxiliary files, and I always have to click the trash button to remove them.  But doing so, I always end with a **name.lol** file (list of listings?) that I don't want to have each time I compile a document.  Why it isn't trashed like the other &%$# files?  It is very cumbersome to always have to trash all these pesky files that I don't want/need.  Is there a way to configure TeXShop to automatically remove all these?  And even when I press the trash button, why the **.lol** file is still there?

Comment: you _need_ .lol .lof .lot .aux, that's why latex writes them, why would your editor delete them? you could presumably add .lol to the standard list of extensions that are removed when cleaning the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the latest version of TeXShop, select Help -> TeXShop Manual and then look in section 10 where this is explained. Different files are used for different purposes, and are generated for different reasons during a compilation. For example, if you need to build an index you will generate files that would not otherwise be generated if do not need an index. As David Carlisle pointed out all these files are needed in case you do further document processing. The editor has no way of knowing when you are finished. TeXShop's developer decided on a default set of files that could be deleted because these are the most often generated files during a compilation. You can add to this list of files as explained in section 10 of the Manual.

Comment: I never had this lol file before, with **Latexian**.  All temporary and auxiliary files are automatically deleted when we close the document.  There should be an option in TeXShop to have the same behavior.

Comment: You can always submit that as a feature request to Dick Koch, TeXShop's developer, but I predict he would not implement it. The issue of WHICH files to delete is still a problem, though, because different workflows will generate different files.

Comment: I understand that, but TeXShop should at least have a preferences option to automatically delete all auxiliary files (including lol files) after a source is closed.  Only the compiled pdf is desirable.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142635/218142

Comment: @Cham I very often close my editor while still working on my document, and I would loath it if the auxiliary files would be deleted and I would have to redo all the compilations next time I open the editor.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, TeXShop should then give the user the choice (like other apps do).  A simple check box could allow the app to automatically erase all auxiliary files after closing the source code.  To me, it's a pain in the butt to navigate through a long list of useless files just to find a specific code file I have in the list.  This is how I always worked with Latexian for about 15 years.  By default, that check box could be OFF (not deleting files).  It's then up to the user to press that check box (me) or not (you).  I'm very surprised that TeXShop doesn't have that check box!